# How to compile multiple resources files into one dll

Tags: c#, .net

I have multiple .resources file each representing different language.If i include these files into the project and include them as "EmbeddedResource" each resources file gets compiled into a separate dll.Is there a way to compile all into one dll. I am using ResourceManager class

Comment: If they are all in one dll, how does the system know which resource file to use?  The reason they are separate files is that the system will load `fr-FR.dll` or `de-DE.dll` depending on which language you require.

Answer (score 0):

By adding following tag in the csproj file,all the resources gets compiled into the source dll.Copied from the following link
https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/3987

```
<Target Name="_ForceAllResourcesToMainAssembly" AfterTargets="SplitResourcesByCulture">
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource>
      <Culture />
      <WithCulture>false</WithCulture>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```